# Download XML File From URL and Save it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I want to download one xml file that share in GitHub. This is my code but my result is site's xml. Where am I going wrong?

This is my code:

```
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"https://github.com/qazaleh/xml-file/blob/master/result.xml";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
         NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
         if ( urlData )
         {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"result"];
            NSLog(@"Downloading Started %@",filePath);
             //saving is done on main thread
                 [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
         }
}
```

Comment: Change your urlToDownload to @"https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt" and see if you are getting a text file. I suppose the github file is not publicly accessible via url.

Comment: when using this url, urlData in nil.

Comment: I am using this url https://mozilla.org/media urlData is nil. and when using this url: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/licensing/website-content/ download a txt file for site

Comment: I suppose the github file is not publicly accessible via url.

Comment: You need to use github api for fetching files from repositories on github. Take a look here https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

Comment: tanks for your help...